# Add WCF reference within the same solution without adding a service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, azure, cloud

I am working on a project using windows Azure and within an worker role i want to use a webservice to submit some information to it.My question is: Can i use the webservice without adding a service reference to it? or to add it in a certain way that when i publish my project in azure i don't need to change the service reference?

Comment: You want be able to configure the endpoint of the web service?  If so, look at using the app.config file to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect directly using a channel factory. Here's a sample base repository class, which you would override, where T is your Service Contract, such as IMyService,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;

namespace pageengine.clients
{
    public class RepositoryBase<T> : IDisposable
    {

        #region Channel
        protected String roleName;
        protected String serviceName;
        protected String endpointName;
        protected String protocol = @"http";

        protected EndpointAddress _endpointAddress;
        protected BasicHttpBinding httpBinding;
        protected NetTcpBinding tcpBinding;

        protected IChannelFactory channelFactory;
        protected T client;

        protected virtual AddressHeader[] addressHeaders
        {
            get
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected virtual EndpointAddress endpointAddress
        {
            get
            {
                if (_endpointAddress == null)
                {
                    var endpoints = RoleEnvironment.Roles[roleName].Instances.Select(i => i.InstanceEndpoints[endpointName]).ToArray();
                    var endpointIP = endpoints.FirstOrDefault().IPEndpoint;
                    if(addressHeaders != null)
                    {
                        _endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(String.Format("{1}://{0}/{2}", endpointIP, protocol, serviceName)), addressHeaders);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(String.Format("{1}://{0}/{2}", endpointIP, protocol, serviceName));
                    }

                }
                return _endpointAddress;
            }
        }

        protected virtual Binding binding
        {
            get
            {
                switch (protocol)
                {
                    case "tcp.ip":
                        if (tcpBinding == null) tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
                        return tcpBinding;
                    default:
                        //http
                        if (httpBinding == null) httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                        return httpBinding;
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual T Client
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.client == null)
                {
                    this.channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, endpointAddress);
                    this.client = ((ChannelFactory<T>)channelFactory).CreateChannel();
                    ((IContextChannel)client).OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
                    var scope = new OperationContextScope(((IContextChannel)client));
                    addCustomMessageHeaders(scope);
                }
                return this.client; 
            }
        }

        protected virtual void addCustomMessageHeaders(OperationContextScope operationContextScope)
        {
            // Overidden
        }
        #endregion

        #region CTOR
        public RepositoryBase()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Members

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            if (client != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ((ICommunicationObject)client).Abort();
                    }
                    catch { } // Die quietly.
                }
            }
            if (channelFactory != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    channelFactory.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        channelFactory.Abort();
                    }
                    catch { } // Die quietly.
                }
                channelFactory = null;
            }
            _endpointAddress = null;
            httpBinding = null;
            tcpBinding = null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

You are then discovering the endpoint, which will work both in the published and emulated environments. A class extending this base might look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

using pageengine.services.entities.account;
using pageengine.services;

namespace pageengine.clients.accounts
{
    public class AccountsRepository : RepositoryBase<IAccounts>, IDisposable
    {
        #region CTOR
        public AccountsRepository()
        {
            this.roleName = "EntitiesRole";      // Name of the role my service is on
            this.endpointName = "HttpInternal";  // Name of the endpoint configured on that role. Can be internal or input, tcp or http.
            this.serviceName = "Accounts.svc";   // Name of my service.
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Calls to your service (in this case from an MVC controller action) are then in the form of:

```
    public ActionResult ListAccounts()
    {
        using (var accountsRepository = new AccountsRepository())
        {
            return View("ListAccounts", accountsRepository.Client.ListAccounts());
        }
    }
```